# How to prevent closing emulator when i leave a "blank" on editText?

Tags: java, android

I made a simple app in Android studio which consists in sum two numbers.
It succesfully give me the result, but the problem is when  just put I number
and the another editText section leave in blank, the emulator automatically close. How can i solve this, for example if I put the first number 10 and the other leave in "blank" when I press add should give 10, not close the emulator.
Please help me.

[image]

Code:

```
package com.example.victo.test.feature;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method

    Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Addbutton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            EditText firtsNumberEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.firstNumberEditText);
            EditText secondNumberEditText = (EditText) 
 findViewById(R.id.secondNumberEditText);

            TextView resultTextView = (TextView) 
 findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

            int n1 = 
 Integer.parseInt(firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString());
            int n2 = 
 Integer.parseInt(secondNumberEditText.getText().toString());

            int result = n1 + n2;


            resultTextView.setText(result +"");
        }

    });

}

/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */

 }
```

Thanks for your replies,
It works with the following code:
[image]

Comment: please add relevant code.

Comment: thats most probably of null pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code, you will have to add condition if edittext is null or not.

```
private EditText firtsNumberEditText,secondNumberEditText;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method

        Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Addbutton);
        firtsNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumberEditText);
        secondNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumberEditText);
        TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int n1, n2;

                if (firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString() == "")
                    n1 = 0;
                else n1 = Integer.parseInt(firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString());

                if (secondNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || secondNumberEditText.getText().toString() == "")
                    n2 = 0;
                else n2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumberEditText.getText().toString());

                int result = n1 + n2;

                resultTextView.setText(result +"");
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: Give me this error: Variable 'firtsNumberEditText' is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: @ErnestoPacheco you need to declare this above main method `private EditText firtsNumberEditText,secondNumberEditText;`

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below -

```
if (firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || secondNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter both Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    int result = n1+n2;
}

resultTextView.setText(result +"");
```

or you can use below

```
if (firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString() == "")
                n1 = 0;
            else n1 = Integer.parseInt(firtsNumberEditText.getText().toString());

            if (secondNumberEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || secondNumberEditText.getText().toString() == "")
                n2 = 0;
            else n2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumberEditText.getText().toString());

            int result = n1 + n2;

            resultTextView.setText(result +"");
```

Comment: Gives me this error: Operator '==' cannot aplied to 'adroid.Widget.EditText'

Comment: please check my updated ans first one for attention and second one if you don't want attention...